# How to dry a fish for grill

Tags: fish, grilling, drying

Whenever I grill a fish (red snapper), even after grilling for a recommended grill time (about 10 to 15 mins), it comes out no less juicy compared to when it was put to grill. And when put in a plate, its skin is like floating on its flesh due to moisture.

I need a complete dry fish after the grilling is done with crispy skin, How to achieve that?

Note: I dont know how to dry a fish before grilling, I am assuming that all the drying can be done during grill with heating (which currently doesnt happen), any tip that works is welcome.

Comment: Are you wrapping the fish in aluminium foil when you put it in the grill? if so, stop doing that. You could try to fry it too.

Comment: Sounds like you're deliberately trying to achieve a drier texture, which is nearly the exact opposite of what most grilled-fish recipes will aim to deliver. We may be able to help more if you edit your question to include the exact recipe or method that you're using so that we can recommend specific improvements.

Comment: no, no aluminium foil, currently i take out of the freezer, wait for it to become a little soft and flexible (melt ice), apply some spices and put on grill

Comment: any recipe that would work :) currently what i do is stated above, and what i want is crispy dry skin after the grill

Comment: The fish must be fresh. not frozen; when thawing, there will be a lot more moisture in the fish that will leak out.

Answer (score 1):

You could pack it in dry salt for a while to suck some fluid out via osmotic pressure. Should end up with damp salt and a drier fish. I'd guess if you only packed the outside and brushed it off before grilling it might not have too much salt transfer inwards to oversalt the fish, but I have NOT tried it, just speculating on a method that should work.

Comment: This is what I do with fish that's been frozen and it works well. I brush it off with a paper towel and have never found it too salty.

Answer (score 0):

Paper towels are your best friend!

Comment: Before or after grilling?

Comment: it wont make the skin crispy